# JSON response and NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am new in the iOS development and i am calling the web service that returns me data like

```
[
    {
        "ID": "3416a75f4cea9109507cacd8e2f2aefc3416a75f4cea9109507cacd8e2f2aefc",
        "Name": "2M Enerji"
    },
    {
        "ID": "072b030ba126b2f4b2374f342be9ed44072b030ba126b2f4b2374f342be9ed44",
        "Name": "Çedaş"
    },
    {
        "ID": "093f65e080a295f8076b1c5722a46aa2093f65e080a295f8076b1c5722a46aa2",
        "Name": "Çelikler"
    },
    {
        "ID": "7cbbc409ec990f19c78c75bd1e06f2157cbbc409ec990f19c78c75bd1e06f215",
        "Name": "Çoruh EDAŞ"
    },
    {
        "ID": "70efdf2ec9b086079795c442636b55fb70efdf2ec9b086079795c442636b55fb",
        "Name": "İçdaş"
    }
]
```

Now i am trying to get it in the array , the array will be seperate for the name and id  , i am done till taking in NSDICT following is my code

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"finish loading");
    NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes] 
                                                     length:[webData length] 
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *responsewith = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData 
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //providerData =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:webData];
    providerDropData = [NSString stringWithFormat:responsewith];
    NSLog(@"drop %@",providerDropData);

    NSArray *providerData = [providerDropData valueForKey:@"ID"];
    NSLog(@"jey %@",responsewith);
    NSLog(@"resonser %@",responsewith);
    NSLog(@"laoding data %@",loginStatus);
    //greeting.text = loginStatus;
    [loginStatus release];
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
```

When i tried saving the `NSDictionary` to the `NSArray` for `@"ID"` the application get crashed.

Please help

Comment: NSDICT??? what is that?

Comment: "the application get crashed" - this is very descriptive. Care to explain what this means and what the error is ?

Comment: You need to enumerate through your dictionary and add the string objects to an array.

Comment: Using a whole json response as a string format is pretty bad idea.

Comment: NSDICT is NSDICTONERY @Reformer

Comment: Hey the response is NSArray and then with in that array you have one dictionary as an object of type NSDictionary .

Comment: `NSArray *providerData = [providerDropData valueForKey:@"ID"];`... what do you expect from this line to do?

Comment: Where are you converting the JSON to an NSArray?

Comment: Also, `providerDropData = [NSString stringWithFormat:responsewith];` is simply an expensive (and dangerous) way to assign `responsewith` to `providerDropData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch data from JSON like below way as well,

```
    id  jsonObjectData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData error:&error];
    if(jsonObjectData){
    NSMutableArray *idArray = [jsonObjectData mutableArrayValueForKeyPath:@"ID"];
    NSMutableArray *nameArray = [jsonObjectData mutableArrayValueForKeyPath:@"Name"];
}
```

Comment: if(providerDropData){
        idArray = [providerDropData mutableArrayValueForKeyPath:@"ID"];
        NSMutableArray *nameArray = [providerDropData mutableArrayValueForKeyPath:@"Name"];
        providerData = [providerDropData mutableArrayValueForKey:@"ID"];
        NSLog(@"%d count of array",providerData.count);
    }

this works now i have save in providerData and it display correct count but didnt show in my table can you please help ?

Answer (score 1):

You simply want to use `NSJSONSerialization`

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:&error];
if (!results)
    NSLog(@"%s: JSONObjectWithData error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

// get the first provider id

NSString *providerData = results[0][@"ID"];
```

Comment: NSString *providerData = results[0][@"ID"]; this like gives error `expected method to read element not found in object type of NSDictonary`

Comment: @user3089900 replace `NSDictionary *results` with `NSArray *results`

Comment: [6:22:18 PM] Laurel John: 2014-01-13 18:21:14.554 Engerjit[885:11303] -[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript(inlove): unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xecb60b0
2014-01-13 18:21:14.555 Engerjit[885:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKeyedSubscript(inlove): unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xecb60b0'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @user3089900 Looks like an array within an array, rather than a dictionary within an array.

Comment: no error now but its not giving me any result when i nslog my `providerData`

Comment: @user3089900 Given the JSON provided, the above works for me. Are you sure about the JSON (or did you try to simplify it when posting your question)? Do a `NSLog` of `results` and confirm that it really is an array of dictionaries and that the dictionaries each have a key called `ID` (case sensitive).

Comment: @user3089900 - NSLog `results`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the data  to `NSDictionary` by parsing, then you can extract using KVP.

```
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: i did webdata is my NSDATA

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary * providerDropData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData error:&error];
NSLog(@"drop %@",providerDropData);

NSMutableArray *providerData = [NSMutableArray new];
NSString *key = @"ID";
for (key in providerDropData){
     NSLog(@"Key: %@, Value %@", key, [providerDropData objectForKey: key]);
    [providerData addObject:[providerDropData objectForKey:key]];
}

NSLog("ID Array = %@", providerData]);
}
```

Comment: If you want an array of those `ID` values, you can also just `NSArray *providerData = [providerDropData valueForKey:@"ID"];`.

Comment: 2014-01-13 18:36:32.604 Engerjit[1042:11303] -[__NSArrayM objectForKey(inlove): unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75c3250
2014-01-13 18:36:32.605 Engerjit[1042:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey(inlove): unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75c3250'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @user3089900 That error (and the one you cited above in the other answer) suggests that the JSON is _not_ what you said it was. Log the `providerDropData` (or `results` in my answer) and update your question with that.